# how to mark multiple lat/long in google map search url

Tags: google-maps

how to mark multiple lat/long in google map search url
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393
the above example has one set of longitude and latitude specifeid. How can we give more than one latitude and longitude in url, so that it marks both in map

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/mymaps), create a new map and add all the markers you want using the marker icon in the toolbar under the searchbar: [image]

Then, you can share your map with anyone using the Share button in the box at the top left.